# How do I delete (not close) an epic in ZenHub?

Tags: zenhub

I accidentally created an issue when setting up my first board. I have no need to delete the Issue - it has nothing attached to it. But I just want to keep my board clean.

Is there a way to actually delete this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit late to the party, but according to ZenHub docs

> It is not possible to delete a Release once it has been created.
> Closing a Release will remove it from your Board and filters. This
> release will only be visible to users scrolling through the list of
> closed releases in the Release report tab.